# Swift: Variadic Return for Calculated Properties

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there any way to give a variadic return type for a calculated property?

```swift
enum ViewElements {
    case headline, subline, bullets
    
    var localizedText: String... { // variadic return type would be nice
        switch self {
        case .headline: return "headline".localized
        case .subline: return "subline".localized
        case .bullets: return ["bullet1", "bullet2", "bullet3"].map { $0.localized }
        }
    }
}
```

So I can iterate flexible like that:

```swift
ForEach(ViewText.bullets.localizedText, id: \.self) { text in ... }
```

Comment: Why not return an array? _If_ you could return a variadic type the receiver would have to treat it as a possible array anyway.

Comment: Because when you want to get the text for a single element, you don't want to unwrap the optional first element, example: ViewText.headline.localizedText.first

Comment: And how would you handle a variadic value in a better way?

Comment: You need to do Text("headline") for your localisations otherwise the label on screen won't update when the user's language settings are changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return an `Array`. Variadic return types are not supported in Swift, only variadic input arguments are.

You can wrap the single `String` return values in an Array to achieve your goals.

```
enum ViewElements {
    case headline, subline, bullets
    
    var localizedText: [String] {
        switch self {
        case .headline: return ["headline".localized]
        case .subline: return ["subline".localized]
        case .bullets: return ["bullet1", "bullet2", "bullet3"].map { $0.localized }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dávid, maybe Apple will provide Variadic Return Type in a later Swift version... :)